# javascript that is supposed to show/hide text according to url is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code is supposed to show/hide a text based on the page's url, but it's not working:

```
    var pages = window.location.href;    
if(pages == "page1.html"){
    //display page 1 text
}
else if(pages == "page2.html"){
    //display page 2 text
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yp8h2moe/1/

I tested it localy, didn't work, so I tested with jsfiddle, but unfortunately every time you save a jsfiddle, you get a new url.

UPDATE

Here is the updated code, I was able to run it specifying the file extention, but I need it to run with the url only:

```
<script>
var pages = window.location.href;    
if( pages.split('/').pop() === 'http://akecheta.com/free-blogger-templates/' ) {
    document.write('<b>Hello World 1</b>');
}
else if( pages.split('/').pop() === 'http://akecheta.com/free-blogger-templates/' ) {
    document.write('<b>Hello World 2</b>');
}
</script>
```

**THE SOLUTION**
[How can I insert HTML text in Javascript the right way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26685846/how-can-i-insert-html-text-in-javascript-the-right-way)

Answer (score 2):

The value of `href` is usually an absolute URL so you have to use `.indexOf()` as follows:

```
var pages = window.location.href;    
if(pages.indexOf("page1.html") > -1){
    //display page 1 text
}
else if(pages.indexOf("page2.html") > -1 ){
    //display page 2 text
}
```

Alternatively you could use `.split()` and `.pop()`, assuming your urls do not have query strings:

```
if( pages.split('/').pop() === 'page1.html' ) {
//...
```

**UPDATE**

When using **absolute URLs** or larger parts thereof, you do not need to use `.split()` and `.pop()`. Bear in mind that `split` creates an array whereas `pop` obtains the last element of that array. You won't be needing this process with **absolute URLs**.

```
var pages = window.location.href;    
if( pages.indexOf( 'http://akecheta.com/free-blogger-templates/' ) > -1 ) {
    document.write('<b>Hello World 1</b>');
}
else if( pages.indexOf( 'http://akecheta.com/free-blogger-templates/xx' ) > -1 ) {
    document.write('<b>Hello World 2</b>');
}
```

Comment: So I tested your code, it worked without the use of jquery, great, but there is a problem, I can't put it to work on a url without specificy the file extension. Let's say I have http://sitedotcom/page1 (A search engine friendly url) and need the text to appear in that page only, how do I do that? I'll edit my topic right with the updated code, so you can have an idea of what I'm talking about.

Comment: Check out the updated answer. I noticed that the two absolute URLs you provided are the same so only the `then` part of the `if` will run when there's a matching URL.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer `iff` it was helpful.

Comment: Should I replace that "xx" with something else?

Comment: Yes. I had to make it different, otherwise you would not need the `else` clause.

Comment: Then I believe I don't need the else. I need the text to appear only in the first url.

Comment: We're almost there, give me a solution here and rest assured that I'll mark your answer as the best one :)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because in your jsfiddle `var pages` is  `"http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/ "`

try to console.log it and make sure to trim it too if it is needed..
In your case for page1.html etc.. you have to compare it to the full/absolute path

Answer (score 0):

If your URL is http://wwww.example.com/page1.html, then you need the URL path.  So, code will look something like below

```
var pages = location.pathname;    
if(pages == "/page1.html"){
  //display page 1 text
}
else if(pages == "/page2.html"){
   //display page 2 text
}
```